# If $\lim_{x\to \infty} \log_{2} (x^2+5x) -2\log_{2} (ax+1) +2=0$, find $a$.

Tags: limits, solution-verification

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \log_2 \frac{x^2+5x}{ax^2 +2ax +1} +\log_2 4$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty} \log_2 \frac{4x^2 +20 x}{ax^2 +2ax+1}$$
$$=\log_2 \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{4x^2 +20x}{ax^2+2ax+1}$$
$$=\log_2 \frac 4a=0$$
$$a=4$$
Given answer is $2$

I think I went wrong in the third step, but I am not sure about it. I need my solution verified.

Comment: $ax^2$ should be $a^2x^2$. $\log_2\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\log_2 f(x)$ is continiousity of $\log_2$, it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the steps need to be $a^2x^2$ instead of $ax^2$. So finally
$$\log_2(4/a^2)=0 \implies a=2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Make your life simpler taking into account that $x$ is very large. So
$$ \log_{2} (x^2+5x) \sim  \log_{2} (x^2)= 2\log_{2} (x)$$
$$ \log_{2} (ax+1)\sim \log_{2} (ax)=\log_{2} (a)+\log_{2} (x)$$
$$ \log_{2} (x^2+5x) -2\log_{2} (ax+1) +2\sim 2\log_{2} (x)-2\log_{2} (a)-2\log_{2} (x)+2$$
$$ \log_{2} (x^2+5x) -2\log_{2} (ax+1) +2\sim -2\log_{2} (a)+2 \implies \log_{2} (a)=1\implies a=2$$

**Edit**

If you want to go beyond the limit itself, write
$$ \log_{2} (x^2+5x)=\log_{2} (x^2)+\log_2 \left(1+\frac{5}{x}\right)=2\log_{2} (x)+\log_2 \left(1+\frac{5}{x}\right)$$
$$ \log_{2} (ax+1)=\log_{2} (x)+\log_2 \left(a+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$ \log_{2} (x^2+5x) -2\log_{2} (ax+1) +2=\log_2 \left(1+\frac{5}{x}\right)-2\log_2 \left(a+\frac{1}{x}\right)+2$$ Now, use Taylor twice with
$$\log_2(1+\epsilon)=\frac{\epsilon }{\log_e (2)}-\frac{\epsilon ^2}{2 \log_e (2)}+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ which would give for the expression
$$2\left(1-\frac{ \log_e (a)}{\log (2)}\right)+\frac{5 a-2}{a x \log_e
   (2)}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ If you make $a=2$, you then have
$$\frac{4}{x \log_e (2)}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ which is not much.

Comment: Upto what extent can such approximations be used?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \log\dfrac{(x^2 + 5x)}{(ax + 1)^2} = -2 \Rightarrow \log \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{(x^2 + 5x)}{(ax + 1)^2} = \log \dfrac{1}{a^2} = -2 \Rightarrow a = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

You messed up in the first step, since $$(ax+1)^2 = a^{\color{red}{2}}x^2 + 2ax + 1$$

You left out the power of $2$ for $a$. Everything after that is fine. You would end up with $$\log_2 \frac{4}{a^2} = 0 \to a = 2$$

An alternate way to find the limit is write $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \log_2\left(x^2\left(1 + \frac{5}{x}\right) \right)  - 2\log_2 \left(ax\left(1 + \frac{1}{ax}\right)  \right) + 2\right)$$

Then this becomes $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \log_2(x^2) -2\log_2(ax) + 2 \right)$$ since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \log_2\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right) = 0$.

Then, this becomes $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 2\log_2(x) - 2\log_2(a) - 2\log_2(x) + 2 \right) = 0 \to a = 2$$